mssq server failed to active after upgrade from 22.04 to 23.10
sudo systemctl status mssql-server
× mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mssql-server.service.d
└─override.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2024-05-04 18:45:16 EEST; 1min 28s ago
Duration: 11ms
Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
Process: 5534 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=exited, status=127)
Main PID: 5534 (code=exited, status=127)
CPU: 3ms
ماي 04 18:45:16 ninja-box systemd[1]: Stopped mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
ماي 04 18:45:16 ninja-box systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
ماي 04 18:45:16 ninja-box systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ماي 04 18:45:16 ninja-box systemd[1]: Failed to start mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
ماي 04 18:45:17 ninja-box systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
ماي 04 18:45:17 ninja-box systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ماي 04 18:45:17 ninja-box systemd[1]: Failed to start mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
ماي 04 18:46:42 ninja-box systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
ماي 04 18:46:42 ninja-box systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ماي 04 18:46:42 ninja-box systemd[1]: Failed to start mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
